# I am trying to add used UID into the realtime database?

Tags: javascript, firebase, user-interface, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to add used UID into the real-time database but when I do that the UID comes back defined and I am not sure why that is.

Here is my JS

```
    var userUID;

    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
        if (user) {
            userUID = user.uid;
        } else {}
    });


    //Creating the Database for the Users using realtime mf (SAVE THE DATABSE INFO)
    database.ref('users/' + userUID).set({
        Name: name,
        Email: email,
        Password: password,
        Industry: industry, 
        Birthday: birthday
    });
```

and here is what the output is in the real-time database

[image: Here is the output]

Thank you

Comment: `onAuthStateChanged()` is asynchronous. Can't access new value of `userUID` until it completes

Comment: @charlietfl I’m confused as to what that means sorry l,

Answer (score 1):

As charlie commented, the `onAuthStateChanged` gets fired asynchronously. That means that your `set()` call currently runs before `userUID` is set.

You can most easily see this by adding a few well-placed log statements:

```
console.log("Starting to listen to auth state");
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
  console.log("Got auth state");
});
console.log("Started to listen to auth state");
```

When you run this code, the output is:

> Starting to listen to auth state
>
> Started to listen to auth state
>
> Got auth state

That's probably not what you expected, but it completely explains why you get `undefined` in the database. By the time you run `database.ref('users/' + userUID).set({...` the `userUID` hasn't been set yet.

The fix is simple: move the code that need `userUID` into the method that get it:

```
var userUID;

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
    if (user) {
        userUID = user.uid;

        database.ref('users/' + userUID).set({
            Name: name,
            Email: email,
            Password: password,
            Industry: industry, 
            Birthday: birthday
        });
    }
});
```